# Почему UDF убивают параллелизм?

Tags: sql, sql-server

В общем, если использовать встроенные скалярки, то параллелзим не пропадает, но если написать свою скалярку и не важно есть ли там циклы или там считается 2+2, то параллелизм из плана пропадает.

В SQL Server 2019, вроде, появятся inline-функции, которые в некоторых случаях не убивают параллелизм, однако мне все равно не понятно, почему для UDF'ов нельзя генерировать оптимальные планы запросов?

Например, UDF CLR'ки не убивают параллелизм, хоть и есть затраты на кроссдоменное взаимодействие.

В других СУБД такая же политика?

Comment: Сказать, что с UDF совсем нет параллелизма нельзя. Т.е. план с участием T-SQL UDF конечно всегда последовательный, но то, что находится внутри UDF, может иметь параллельный план. При вызове UDF происходит переключение контекста (при inlining-е лишних переключений не будет). Может быть это накладывает какие-то ограничения. Допустим запрос c UDF может обновлять таблицу, из которой эта же UDF и читает данные. Может быть есть какая-то опасность получить некорректный результат или intra-query дедлок, т.к. весь запрос "от и до" по идее должен выполняться одним и тем же набором worker-ов.

Comment: Либо просто не генерится параллельный план, т.к. внутри UDF могут быть обращения (в т.ч. через цепочку вложенных вызовов) к каким-то системным функциям или sys.dm_* объектам (многое из этого подавляет параллелизм и без использования T-SQL UDF). С подстановкой легче проверить, есть ли что-то запрещённое или нет.

Answer (score 1):

По идее причина кроется в том, что в UDF могут быть побочные эффекты, либо они могут зависеть не только от входных параметров, но и от некоторых внешних факторов.

Плюс в UDF может использоваться менеджер памяти, который не поддерживает многопоточную работу (как том у SQL сервера, на новые коннекты создаются отдельные потоки или процессы?)

Как следствие, т.к. сервер ничего не знает о конкретной UDF он запускает все в однопоточном режиме